# FeatherLight Galleries with Videos do not have Navigation

Tags: featherlight.js

My Featherlight galleries could include images or iframe videos (such as Vimeo), even mixed types, however if there is a video in the gallery, there are no Prev or Next buttons.

https://jsfiddle.net/anobjectx/97scfbxm/28/

Not sure why StackOverflow is requiring code in the question when there is a jsFiddle link, but since that is the case

```
    const $panels = jQuery('.gallery-collection');
    $panels.each(function(){
        const $panel = jQuery(this);
        $panel.featherlightGallery({
            variant: 'gal',
            filter: 'a'
        });
    });
```

First tried the declarative approach, then when there were problems I switched to featherlightGallery() but no difference with regards to navigation.

Comment: the Featherlight source appears to say that the navigation controls are inserted after the -content div, however this div is not appearing in my slides with iframes.